# swapExactTokensForEthSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens function

Tags: solidity

What is the difference between swapExactTokensForEthSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens and simple swapExactTokensForEth?

please anyone explain it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `swapExactTokensForETH` function swaps a specific amount of tokens for ETH. It does not support tokens with a fee on transfer, so if such tokens are involved, the transaction may fail. The function takes five parameters: the amount of tokens to send, the minimum output tokens expected, the token route, the recipient address, and the transaction deadline.

The `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` function is similar, but it can handle tokens with a fee on transfer. This allows successful swaps with such tokens without causing transaction reverts. The function is ideal for tokens implementing fee mechanisms like reflection tokens. The recipient must be a smart contract capable of receiving ETH. Both functions require a series of token pairs with liquidity to execute successfully.

For code samples check the documentation: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02